# Draw/update circles in rect - nested selections confusion

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to get a layout that would, for each object in the data array:

1. append a `rect` or a `g` element that will serve as container
2. inside or on top of this, append a `circle` for each of the coordinates.

Below is a mock-up of how the data is massaged before I'm trying to append to the DOM (at the top of the `update()` function in the block below):

```
[{
    label: 'foo',
    circles: [
      { x: 0, y: 10 },
      { x: 10, y: 10 }
    ]
},{
...
}]
```

The drawing and updating of the rect elements seems to be working fine, but I am getting the selection and joins confused for the circles.

Here's the block: http://blockbuilder.org/basilesimon/91f75ab5209a62981f11d30a81f618b5

With

```
var dots = rects.selectAll('.dots')
```

I can select the right data below but can't draw it.

Could you help me getting the selections right so I can draw and update both the `rect` and the `circle`, please?

---

Thank you Gerard for your help. [This is my current state](http://blockbuilder.org/basilesimon/91f75ab5209a62981f11d30a81f618b5), but I've pitted myself into a hole by running a `for` loop instead of d3 selections.

I wonder if I couldn't nest the `circles` in `g` elements after building a new  data object like so:

```
  var data = dataset.map(function(d) {
    var circles = d3.range(d.amount).map(function(i) {
      return {
        x: (i % 5)*20,
        y: (i / 5 >> 0)*20
      }
    });
    return {
      label: d.label,
      dots: circles
    };
  });
```

From each object in `data`, we'll append a `g`, and inside each `g` we'll append the `circles`. Any help appreciated, since this will affect the `dots + i` used by the update pattern...

**[New question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938809/how-to-nest-selections-and-appends-instead-of-a-for-loop-over-data-array)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
var dots = svg.selectAll('dots')
```

You're selecting something that doesn't exist. Because of that, your "enter" selection will **always** contain all the data, and your "exit" selection will **always** be empty.

The solution is changing it for something like this:

```
var dots = svg.selectAll(".dots" + i)
```

And, in the enter selection, setting the classes:

```
.attr("class", "dots" + i)
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks (with some other minor changes): https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/4c2e1d66f1ab890da983465a4f84ca9b

Comment: Interesting, and that makes sense indeed. I wouldn't have thought of that... The examples I've perused were all about one container element, hence no need for `(class + i)`. Thank you!

Comment: I realise however that I've pitted myself into a hole with this `for` loop here, instead of having a parent selection with  the objects from `data`, and a child selection with the `circles`, based on `d.amount`. I'll amend the original question.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that. You normally don't need a for loop using D3.

Comment: I've put in the original question a new description and way to generate the data object we need... would you mind  taking a look? Thank you

Comment: As this is **another** issue, I suggest you posting **another** question. If you ask this here, I'm the only one reading it. If you post another question, everybody's gonna read it.

Comment: Oops, good shout. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938809/how-to-nest-selections-and-appends-instead-of-a-for-loop-over-data-array